# Why does the IE display the bootstrap theme wrong? What could I change in the style (css)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I use this template http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html for twitter boostrap.

If I opened the site with the Internet Explorer (IE) 10: Header image is not on the top!

I need the same layout in the IE. What could I change in the style file? Please give me a hint! Thanks very much.

**IE 10 (wrong):**
[image: IE 10]
**Chrome (right):**
[image: Chrome]

Comment: would like a jsfiddle. It is impossible to answer _What could I change in the style file?_ (or hint on some other error) without knowing what you are doing.

Comment: I will use the style http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html. Please open this site in IE 9 or 10. jsfiddle is not required because I would copy the page 1:1. Thanks for your help [I have updated the question].

Comment: Tried to start a windows and download IE10, no luck - cannot install IE10 (need a servicepack or something like that) but you are absolutely right, try out the carousel-example on http://netrenderer.com/ - it reproduces exactly what you describe above for IE10. Think it is either bootstrap that is not taken some IE10 issues in concern, or the IE10 preview that is just doing a bad job. Have you tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` ? The markup is valid html5 (if you forget the missing alt-attributes).

Comment: Does not work. I have updated the URL in the post. It contains your suggestion. Download IE10: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-10/worldwide-languages

Comment: I have opened both of the sites in IE9 and they look fine. No problem with the image or nav bar. So I would remove IE9 from the question. However as @davidkonrad said, using http://netrenderer.com/ to display the IE10 result shows the issue you are having. You should report the issue and hopefully they will get it fixed asap: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues

Comment: Yes, I agree. It is likely to be a bootstrap issue. This carousel-example is fairly new, 29.10, http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/10/29/bootstrap-2-2-0-released/ so it is probably not tested thoroughly (!?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`!
Thanks for your helping.